# Connecting a printer to pi zero w

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, cups

I am trying to convert my aspberry pi zero w into a printer server. I understand how to setup the software to make it into a print server via cups.

But what has flummoxed so far is how to connect the printer to the raspberry pi zero physically!

My printer has a USB type b as output, so I use a USB type B to USB type A cable to connect it to my PC.

Now how do I connect my printer to my raspberry pi zero? Should I use a OTG cable or an adapter? (Micro USB to type A adapters are hard to find!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires an OTG cable. I was able to detect my printer via lsusb.

Looks like USB on the Raspberry pi zero is configured to be run as a slave device unlike the other Raspberry pi boards where it is configured as a master device.

If anyone has an explanation for this, would love to hear it!